# Get minimal visible value in plot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using current version of JFreechart, plot is XYPlot type.

After zooming-in xyplot with

```
zoomablePlot.zoomDomainAxis(...);
zoomablePlot.zoomRangeAxis(...);
```

I would like to get minimal visible value on domain axis.
The DataRange object

```
//plot is XYPlot type
Range dataRange = plot.getDataRange(...);
```

contains only 'global' minimum value, not currently displayed.

Comment: What classes/library do you use? Please provide more info.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that tags will be cleared enough.

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you what you want.

```
plot.getRangeAxis().getLowerBound();
```